# Rectangles changing colors when interacted with

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

The program is supposed to make a grid where all rectangles start black and if clicked or dragged they turn white. So far my program is able to make the rectangle you click or drag white, but it doesn't memorize or remember which one I clicked to make them stay white until you click them again. Maybe I would call the change using the mouse listener or maybe by creating an LinkedList , I just can't figure out the easiest solution.

```
public class Clicky extends JFrame {

private static class Board extends JPanel {

private double BRICK_WIDTH = 20;
private double BRICK_HEIGHT = 20;

public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
public double width = screenSize.getWidth();
public double height = screenSize.getHeight();

private int COLS = (int)(width/BRICK_WIDTH);
private int ROWS =(int)(height/BRICK_HEIGHT);
private Color CO = Color.BLACK;


public Board() {
    System.out.println("WIdth:" + COLS + "Height:" + ROWS);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            mx = e.getX();
            my = e.getY();
            System.out.printf("X: %d Y: %d ", mx, my);
            repaint();
        }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            mx = e.getX();
            my = e.getY();

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawBricks(g);
}


private double x;
private double y;

private void drawBricks(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D brick = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= ROWS; j++)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a <= COLS; a++) {
            brick.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
            brick.fill(rect);
            if (mx > x && mx < x + BRICK_WIDTH && my > y && my < y + BRICK_HEIGHT) {
                if (brick.getColor() == Color.BLACK) {
                    CO = Color.white;
                    brick.setColor(CO);
                    brick.fill(rect);
                repaint();
                }
                else {
                    CO = Color.BLACK;
                    brick.setColor(CO);
                    brick.fill(rect);
                repaint();
                }
            }


            brick.setColor(Color.gray);
            brick.draw(rect);
            x += BRICK_WIDTH;
        }
        repaint();
        x = 0;
        y += BRICK_HEIGHT;
        }

}
public int mx = -100;
public int my = -100;
}

public Clicky() {

setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    //mai bine cu exit on close
setSize(800, 820);
add(new Board());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new Clicky().setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use an 2-dimensional boolean array that represents the status of rectangles. When the color changes, change the value of the array-element and set the color depending on it:

```
public class Clicky extends JFrame {

private static class Board extends JPanel {

    private double BRICK_WIDTH = 20;
    private double BRICK_HEIGHT = 20;

    public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public double width = screenSize.getWidth();
    public double height = screenSize.getHeight();

    private int COLS = (int) (width / BRICK_WIDTH);
    private int ROWS = (int) (height / BRICK_HEIGHT);
    private Color CO = Color.BLACK;

    private boolean[][] isWhite = new boolean[COLS + 1][ROWS + 1];

    public Board() {
        System.out.println("WIdth:" + COLS + "Height:" + ROWS);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mx = e.getX();
                my = e.getY();
                System.out.printf("X: %d Y: %d ", mx, my);
                isWhite[(int) (mx / BRICK_WIDTH)][(int) (my
                        / BRICK_HEIGHT)] = !isWhite[(int) (mx / BRICK_WIDTH)][(int) (my / BRICK_HEIGHT)];
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                mx = e.getX();
                my = e.getY();
                isWhite[(int) (mx / BRICK_WIDTH)][(int) (my
                        / BRICK_HEIGHT)] = !isWhite[(int) (mx / BRICK_WIDTH)][(int) (my / BRICK_HEIGHT)];
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawBricks(g);
    }

    private double x;
    private double y;

    private void drawBricks(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D brick = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= ROWS; j++) {
            for (int a = 0; a <= COLS; a++) {
                if (isWhite[a][j]) {
                    brick.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                } else {
                    brick.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                }
                Rectangle2D.Double rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
                brick.fill(rect);

                brick.setColor(Color.gray);
                brick.draw(rect);
                x += BRICK_WIDTH;
            }
            repaint();
            x = 0;
            y += BRICK_HEIGHT;
        }

    }

    public int mx = -100;
    public int my = -100;
}

public Clicky() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // mai bine cu exit on close
    setSize(800, 820);
    add(new Board());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Clicky().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
}
```